# Elsa workflow designer client side API

Tags: api, client-side, elsa-workflows

I have to persist / save workflow using custom javascript code, not by using built-in designer publish button. So is there any client side API like

```
const elsaStudioRoot = document.querySelector('elsa-studio-root');
```

that is using for registering custom plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The `elsa-studio-root` element does not expose any methods or services that you can leverage, but it would make sense for it to do. You could create an issue and/or submit a PR.

Alternatively, or as a temporary workaround, you could write a plugin that captures the `ElsaStudio` service, which provides access to the `elsaClientFactory` factory method.

This factory method produces an instance of `ElsaClient`, which offers direct API access to the workflow server, which exposes an endpoint to update workflow definitions.

For example (untested code):

```js
// Declare a variable you can access from wherever you want.
let elsaClientFactory = null;

// Declare an Elsa plugin.
function CaptureElsaClientFactoryPlugin(elsaStudio) {

  // Capture the elsa client factory method.
  elsaClientFactory = elsaStudio.elsaClientFactory;
}

// Register the plugin.
elsaStudioRoot.addEventListener('initializing', e => {
  const elsa = e.detail;
  elsa.pluginManager.registerPlugin(CaptureElsaClientFactoryPlugin);
});

// Retrieve an elsa client service.
var elsaClient = elsaClientFactory();

// Save some workflow definition
await elsaClient.workflowDefinitionsApi.save({
  workflowDefinitionId: 'some workflow definition ID',
  name: 'optional',
  displayName: 'optional',
  description: 'optional',
  publish: true, // or false if you don't want to publish but save as draft.
  activities: [],
  connections: []
  // etc. See https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/blob/master/src/designer/elsa-workflows-studio/src/services/elsa-client.ts#L377 for a full list of fields you can specify.
});
```

Comment: yes, I have used this plugin support for customization of properties. let me try your suggested code... thank you so much :)

Comment: I have tested your code, successfully saved the workflow...